# Unable to create a constant value of type 'DAL.MediaGallery'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have seen many questions like this in SO but none of them solved my problem. I have following query that is running on VS 2012 but when I execute this in VS 2015, It gives following error-

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'DAL.MediaGallery'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

My query is:

```
var destinations = (from log in db.DestinationGroups
                    where (log.Id == obj.ContentId)
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = log.Id,
                        Title = log.Name,
                        Rating = log.Rating,
                        UserRating = userRating,
                        Destinations = (from log1 in log.Destinations
                                        from log2 in log1.DestinationDatas
                                        where (log1.Id == log2.DestinationId && log1.IsActive == true)
                                        select new
                                        {

                                            DestinationId = log2.DestinationId,
                                            DestinationTitle = log2.Name,
                                            Description = log2.Description,
                                            HowToReach = log2.HowToReach,
                                            FoodAndCuisines = log2.FoodAndCuisines,
                                            Shopping = log2.Shopping,
                                            Transport = log2.Transport,
                                            PlacesOfInterest = from log3 in log1.Places
                                                               from log4 in log3.PlaceDatas
                                                               where ( log3.IsActive == true)
                                                               select new
                                                               {
                                                                   PlaceId = log4.PlaceId,
                                                                   Place = log4.Name
                                                               },
                                            MapUrl = (from log4 in log1.Information select log4.MapImageUrl).FirstOrDefault()
                                        }),



                        ImageUrls = db.MediaGalleries.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == log.Name)).Select(x => new { x.ImageUrl, x.MediaGalleryDatas.FirstOrDefault().Caption })// This line is causing error

                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: it would be helpful to point out which are `DAL.MediaGallery` in your query. It's hard to see where could be the problem.

Comment: It is the last line in the query. Please see the comment in code

Comment: why -1. can you Please specify? :-)

Comment: it was not me, I'm thinking about what could be wrong in your question. Be patient, it's just a downvote, maybe many people hate Anonymous?

Comment: you don't need to change the name, maybe just changing the avatar is enough. Normally I encountered this exception if some object of non-supported type is ***captured into the query***. I don't see that in your query now. It looks fairly OK. In fact what I expected is some possible `NotSupportedException` with other message such as related to *method or property access*. If possible you should provide more info about your `x.MediaGalleryDatas` and `db.MediaGalleries`. Also try commenting out some part of the last query to narrow down where it throws the exception.

Comment: there are two tables in my database named mediaGalleries and mediaGalleryDatas with one to many relationship from mediaGalleries to mediaGalleryDatas. There's another table named Tag with many to many relationship with mediaGalleries. I wrote this query to get all the imageUrls from mediaGalleries table for a tag. mediaGalleryDatas contains different captions for the image.

Comment: This query works fine when I run it in VS 2012 but gives above error on running it on VS 2015. It may be the EF version issue?

Comment: maybe, you can view the app.config file to see what version of EF you have. As I said you should try narrowing down what part of the last query causing the exception (while it all looks fine to me now). Looks like I've never encountered this problem before (and I still stick to VS 2012).

Comment: I am using EF version 5.0.0.0

Comment: Yes I updated it to EF 6.0.1. and everything works correctly now.

Comment: Thanks @Hopeless for your time